# How to call web api with geometry parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I want to call web api with geometry parameter.I try this but it doesn't work

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

```
[Route("api/test/geometry/{Geom}")]
public test Get(geometry Geom)
        {
            using (C_Raw_DataEntities entities = new C_Raw_DataEntities())
            {
               return entities.tests.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Geom.Trim() == Geom.Trim());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of **System.Windows.Media.Animation.Animatable.Geometry** class, it is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
You should consider using other class to have a automatic model conversion.

- System.Windows.Media.CombinedGeometry
- System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry
- System.Windows.Media.GeometryGroup
- System.Windows.Media.LineGeometry
- System.Windows.Media.PathGeometry
- System.Windows.Media.RectangleGeometry
- System.Windows.Media.StreamGeometry

and then cast it to Geometry class for your usage.

Comment: I don't think that is the geometry OP is using. Notice the lower case "g" in `geometry` and the fact that it is entity framework indicating spatial data.

Comment: hi chrysa, i am not able to relate the two, the problem that you have posted and this comment.